# HTML CSS Box with padding and margin and 100% width?

Tags: html, css, border, margin, padding

I have a box `#box` with width: 100%, height: 100%, padding: 5px, margin: 5px; border: 5px;

I need in HTML5 layout correctly display that.

Now i have that:

[image]

But i need fit block in body area.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <style>
    body,html {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #box {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border: 5px solid red;
        padding: 15px;
        margin: 20px;
    }
    </style>

    <body>
    <div id="box">
    Text will be here
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: I see in the answers, box-sizing is now all the rage. Be careful about using that if you do as there are issues with it (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing)  and most people don't use it in their examples.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The browser does excacly what you are telling him to do :)
However I think you don't like the overflow it has.

What happens is that your `#box` expands because of your border and padding. You can make these properties inset, so it does not expand your element. You can do this with `box-sizing`:

```
 #box {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     border: 5px solid red;
     padding: 15px;
     /*margin: 20px;*/
     box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

However you can not do the same with the `margin`, because the element is pushing itself from the body: it does what it supposes to do.

You can make a workaround by doing the same thing as above:

```
body
{
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

*You will use the padding on the body instead of the margin on the `#box`.*

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fRFGk/4)

**Update**

To prevent the double padding space, you should only apply it on the body element (or html, but i prefer the body as that is your visual element in the end).

Comment: +1 for thorough explanation. You could also use `calc()` as an alternative btw: http://jsfiddle.net/fRFGk/3/

Answer (score 3):

According to [w3c specs for Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#box-dimensions)

> The rendered width of a box type element is equal to the sum of its width, left/right border and left/right padding.

So that means the values of `padding` and `border-width` affects the total width of the element. So here you are adding the `15px` of the padding along with `5px` of borders with 100% of actual width of the element.

So overall it exceed the widow size that's why it comes with horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 2):

You should use CSS `box-sizing` property:

```
#box {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}
```

But please note that you will need to use zero `margin` for this to work.

There is a good explanatory article on how this works: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

With CSS3, you can replace border with inset `border-shadow` and margin with transparent border. This way you will have control of all of these parameters: padding, (fake) margin and border:

```
#box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    border:20px solid transparent;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 5px #f00;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 5px #f00; 
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

See a live fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/HXR3r/

Comment: This is probably as close as you'll get, but it does not account for the margin (**border**-box).

Answer (score 1):

You can use css calc()

```
#box {
        border: 5px solid red;
        padding: 15px;
        margin: 20px;
        width: calc(100% - 80px);
        height: calc(100% - 80px);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/5rhrh/)**

Your problem is, which you dint noticed, Assuming just for `height`s

```
height:100%;
border: 5px solid red;
padding: 15px;
margin: 20px;
```

> This makes height = 100% + border (2 x 5) + padding (2 x 15) + margin
>   (2 x 20) = **100% + (10+30+40) px**

which is more than `100%`...hence no `fit block in body area.`.Try reducing with height in percentage for better result!! 
Similar is case for the widths!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Add `box-sizing: border-box;` property in your `#box` And remove `margin: 20px;`

Here is the updated CSS:

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 5px solid red;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Agdg/)