# Tiling the page with CSS

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to tile my page horitontally and vertically, recursively too. E.g. that the page is split into three columns, whereby the third column is split into two rows.

```
<div id="left/>
<div id="right">
    <div id="top">...</div>
    <div id="bottom">...</div>
</div>
```

This fiddle explains what I am talking about: 
https://jsfiddle.net/zuyu1ed7/

This design works, until you start adding content. Giving one of these containers a border, a margin or a padding results in chaos. The whole layout seems to be very sensible.

Also, trying to add an `<div style="width:100%; padding: 10px;"/>` inside these containers has the same layout-destructing effects. This situation trandcends my knowledge about css.

At first I thought of using tables, your best friend if css keeps mocking you. But then I saw that html5 does not longer support most `colgroup`-attributes. So that idea was an dead end.

My question is: How do I split div's horizontally and vertically as shown in the fiddle and be able to add content to the containers?
I am thankful for any solution, but of course I would prefer a solution that works in all browsers.

Comment: I dont see the dividers change when I place content in the div? Just adds text?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377482/html-css-box-with-padding-and-margin-and-100-width

Comment: @Arendax Simple Text works fine, but try adding the padded div I showed into one of the containers. This destroys the whole layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered `flexbox`?
It is basically supported [by all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcj2hqc9/)

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: Blue;
}

#right {
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: Green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 33.33%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#center {
  width: 100%;
  height: 33.33%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 33.34%;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
}

#bottom-left {
  height: 100%;
  width: 35%;
  background-color: Yellow;
}

#bottom-right {
  height: 100%;
  width: 65%;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
  </div>
  <div id="right">
      <div id="top"></div>
      <div id="center"></div>
      <div id="bottom">
          <div id="bottom-left"></div>
          <div id="bottom-right"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think flexbox might be the best way to achieve what I want.

Comment: PS: the fiddle-link did not match the code in your answer, I created an edit.

Comment: You're welcome :) That's strange about the code though, I copied it right from fiddle. meh.